# How to recover program results in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

when I am running a program in sublime, I want to search something, so I typed 'command + F', and then, the program results I have got disappeared, how can I recover them?

Comment: Select *Tools > Build Results > Show Build Results*.

Comment: @ r-stein, I got it, thanks!